# how to run delayed job every week without using whenever?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

How to run the delayed job every 7 days that is every week?

```
Mailers.delay(run_at: 7.days.from_now).send_mail(user)
```

This will run 7 days from now . I want the same job to be run every week. with out using whenever gem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Rufus Scheduler](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler) is a great gem, all Ruby based (no cron)

```
# config/initializer/task_scheduler.rb

require 'rufus-scheduler'

scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new

scheduler.every '7d' do
  user = method_to_get_user_object
  Mailers.send_mail(user).deliver
end
```

Comment: Thanks Steve. This is a thank you comment, content nazis can kiss my back side.

Comment: Thank you for answer! whether is this achieved by delayed job itself.